# How to change rails path so it knows its installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, installation, rvm

I installed rails but it kept saying I didn't and I think its because my PATH is wrong.

When I use this command first

```
source /Users/MyCPUUserName/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Than it shows that I've installed rails. I can use it and deploy commands but if I reopen terminal without issuing that command, it says that rails is not installed. Should I change my Rails $PATH or the path of rvm and for whichever one I do need to change, how do I do that?

Comment: 5 bucks you didn't follow RVM installation guide where it said to add this line to you `.bash_login`

Answer (score 0):

there are few possibilities all end up in repeating proper installation process and reading all the outputs - all of them - if installer or rvm tells you to check something or do something - go and do what you are asked for - it's for you to avoid problems like this.

so:

1. update rvm and shell initialization files:

   ```
   ~/.rvm/bin/rvm get head --auto-dotfiles
   ```
2. make sure there is ruby and it is set to default:

   ```
   ~/.rvm/bin/rvm install ruby
   ~/.rvm/bin/rvm alias create default ruby
   ```
3. make sure rvm is loaded properly - **restart computer** - I know it's a lot but it's the easiest way to ensure your environment is loaded properly
4. check if rvm is loaded:

   ```
   type rvm | head -n 1
   ```

   it should show up something like: `rvm is a function` - other answers are bad and you need get back to step 1. paying more attention to the commands and their outputs
5. if the problems persist on second pass open a ticket for rvm: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues